# Deep copy of graph node

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, graph

I'm solving [LeetCode problem #133](https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/description/):

> Given a reference of a node in a [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Connected_graph) undirected graph.
>
> Return a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) (clone) of the graph.
>
> Each node in the graph contains a value (`int`) and a list (`List[Node]`) of its neighbors.
>
> ```
> class Node {
>     public int val;
>     public List<Node> neighbors;
> }
> ```
>
> #### Test case format:
>
> For simplicity, each node's value is the same as the node's index (1-indexed). For example, the first node with `val == 1`, the second node with `val == 2`, and so on. The graph is represented in the test case using an adjacency list.
>
> **An adjacency list** is a collection of unordered `lists` used to represent a finite graph. Each list describes the set of neighbors of a node in the graph.
>
> The given node will always be the first node with `val = 1`. You must return the **copy of the given node** as a reference to the cloned graph.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the graph is in the range `[0, 100]`.
> - `1 <= Node.val <= 100`
> - `Node.val` is unique for each node.
> - There are no repeated edges and no self-loops in the graph.
> - The Graph is connected and all nodes can be visited starting from the given node.

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;
    Node() {
        val = 0;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};

void clone (
    const Node *NODE,
    Node *node,
    vector<Node *>& nodes,
    vector<bool>& visited
) {
    if ( visited[node->val] ) return;
    else visited[node->val] = true;

    // cout << "On node : " << node->val << endl;

    Node *temp;

    for ( Node* next : NODE->neighbors ) {
        if ( !nodes[next->val] ) {
            temp = new Node(next->val);
            nodes[next->val] = temp;
        }
        temp = nodes[next->val];
        // cout << next->val << " now neighbour of " << node->val << endl;
        (node->neighbors).push_back(temp);

        clone(next, temp, nodes, visited);
    }
}

Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) {

    if ( !node ) return NULL;

    vector<Node *> nodes(101, NULL);
    vector<bool> visited(101, false);

    Node *root = new Node(node->val);

    clone(  node, root, nodes, visited );

    return root;
}

void dfs ( Node *node, vector<bool>& visited ) {
    if ( visited[node->val] ) return;

    visited[node->val] = true;
    cout << node << " (" << node->val << ") ";

    for ( Node *next : node->neighbors ) {
        dfs( next, visited );
    }
}

int main() {
    Node* node1 = new Node(1);
    Node* node2 = new Node(2);
    Node* node3 = new Node(3);
    Node* node4 = new Node(4);

    node1->neighbors.push_back(node2);
    node1->neighbors.push_back(node4);

    node2->neighbors.push_back(node1);
    node2->neighbors.push_back(node3);

    node3->neighbors.push_back(node2);
    node3->neighbors.push_back(node4);

    node4->neighbors.push_back(node1);
    node4->neighbors.push_back(node3);

    Node *root = cloneGraph(node1);

    vector<bool> visited(5, false);
    dfs( root, visited );
    cout << endl;
    
    visited = vector(5, false);
    dfs( node1, visited );
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x55b6eebd4340 (1) 0x55b6eebd4370 (2) 0x55b6eebd4410 (3) 0x55b6eebd4460 (4) 
0x55b6eebd3eb0 (1) 0x55b6eebd3ee0 (2) 0x55b6eebd3f10 (3) 0x55b6eebd3f40 (4)
```

As per the output, the nodes seem to be cloned properly but I get this error upon submitting :

> You must return a copy of all the nodes in the original graph

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't even compile for me, not to mention how to drive your test cases.

Comment: To start with: What's `Node`?

Comment: Short cut: Post a [mcve] as required here in your question please!

Comment: You can go to the question link to execute code so you don't have to set everything up.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Questions needs to be self-contained.

Comment: Probably the best thing you can do for your question is leave leetcode in the dust. Pick out a specific piece of wrong output. Don't be concerned about how that fits in to your final goal. Just pick out one symptom along the lines of "I expect the output `2 3` but get just `3`." Simplify your input and simplify your code to focus on just this particular output. A good result is making your question abstract enough that mentioning "LeetCode problem #133" is of no benefit to your question.

Comment: And creating a [mre] also helps yourself to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your own programs locally on your own system.

Comment: @PriyanshuSahani Nope! You setup questions here according the site policies, and fitting them well, Oki?

Comment: @JaMiT that's the thing, I'm unable to point out the error here, locally the function seems to be working fine and even leetcode doesn't give m meaningful error here but a weird output.

Comment: @PriyanshuSahani so you don't have the exact test case running on leetcode??

Comment: You have not created the `Solution` class that is required for C++ solution code on LeetCode.

Comment: Don't ever `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). And also read [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined the `cloneGraph` as a method of the `Solution` class (which is what LeetCode expects), then there is still this problem:

Whenever you look at a neighbor, you register the created node in the `nodes` vector, but you have not done the same for the very first node (`root`). As a consequence when the root is encountered again, a *new* node is created for it, (and only now it is registered in `nodes`). But as this node is not the one that is referenced by `root`, the final return value is **not** the node that the algorithm registered later.

The fix is simple. Register the `root` node in the `nodes` vector:

```
    Node *root = new Node(node->val);
    nodes[root->val] = root;  // add this line!

    clone(node, root, nodes, visited);

    return root;
```